# Html ahref tag in stringbuilder

Tags: asp.net

I am using html

```
strBody.Append("<span style=\"font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt\"> Hi " + Name + ",<br/><br/> Welcome! <br/><br/>");
strBody.Append("<tr><td style=\"font-weight:bold\">");
strBody.Append("documents for reference are shared in the Account Induction Portal ");
strBody.Append("</td><td>");
strBody.Append("<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a><br/><br/>");
strBody.Append("</td><td>");

strBody.Append("</td></tr>");
strBody.Append("<tbody/></table><br/>");
```

Here href got error i cant include that in string bulider  append without error.Pls help on this

Comment: If you are building up HTML, you really should be using [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx), not `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

you have two sets of parenthesis you must small quote for the url!

```
strBody.Append("<a href='http://www.w3schools.com'>Visit W3Schools</a><br/><br/>");
```

or escape like

```
strBody.Append("<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools</a><br/><br/>"
```

Comment: i have try this but i can see all this line same start from <a />. but i want to just Print Visit word and link in work for background.

Comment: i am print same line in browser like <a href='http://www.w3schools.com'>Visit W3Schools</a><br/><br/>

Answer (score 0):

You don't escape the quotes (`"`) in the following line:

```
// Replace this
strBody.Append("<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a><br/><br/>");

// with either this:
strBody.Append("<a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools</a><br/><br/>");
// or use single quotes inside the string:
strBody.Append("<a href='http://www.w3schools.com'>Visit W3Schools</a><br/><br/>");
```